# matlab How to use a textstring as input parameter in functions

Tags: matlab

I would like to use a dataset filename "AUDUSD" in several functions. It would be easier for me, just to change the filename "AUDUSD" to a more general name like "FX" and then using the abbreviation "FX" in other_matlab functions, e.g. `double()`. But matlab does not know the name "FX" (that should be assigned to the dataset "AUDUSD") in the code below... Any suggestions?

CODE:

```
FX = 'AUDUSD';
load(FX);        %OKAY !!! FX works as input to open file AUDUSD!

Svars = {'S_bid','S_offer'};
Fvars = {'F_bid','F_offer'};

vS = double(FX,Svars);           % FX does NOT work as input for the file AUDUSD
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no double() function that accepts multiple cell arrays as arguments (this is what happens when you call double(FX,Svars)).

If you call double(FX), then each character in FX is interpreted for its ASCII value and then cast to double.  So you get [ 65.0 85.0 68.0 85.0 83.0 68.0 ].  This is the behavior for the double() function if you provide a vector: each individual value in the vector is cast to double.

You'd have to provide more details on what you're trying to accomplish to give any more suggestions.

Comment: Beat me to it by 15 sec. +1. For completeness, could you add a link where the behaviour of double() is explained?

Answer (score 0):

I have a different example, maybe you will better understand my point. The key work I would like to process is as follows:
I have got a folder with "dataset" files. I would like to loop through this folder, entering in any datasetfile, extracting the 2nd and 3rd column of each dataset file, and constructing only ONE new datasetfile with all 2nd and 3rd columns of the datasetfiles.
One problem is that the size of the datasetfiles are not the same, so I tried to translate a datasetfile into a double-matrix and then consolidate all double matrices into ONE double matrx.

Here my code:

```
    folder_string = 'Diss_Data/Raw';
    FolderContent = dir(folder_string);
    No_ds = numel(FolderContent);

    for i = 1:No_ds

        if isdir(FolderContent(i).name)==0

           file_string = FolderContent(i).name;
           file_path = strcat(folder_string,'/',file_string)
           dataset_filename = file_string(1:6);

           load(file_path);            %loads the suggested datasetfile; OKAY
           M = double(dataset_filename);% returns an ASCII code number; WRONG; should     transfer the datasetfile into a matrix M
           vS = M(:,2:3);
           %... to be continued

       end

     end
```